# How can I programmatically create this custom binding?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, basichttpbinding

We've got to access a web service that uses soap11... no problem I'll just set the binding as:

```
BasicHttpBinding wsBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
```

Nope. No dice. So I asked the host of the service why we're having authentication issues and he said that our config needed to have this custom binding:

```
<bindings>
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="lbinding">
            <security  authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" 
                messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11" 
                securityHeaderLayout="Strict" 
                includeTimestamp="false"
                requireDerivedKeys="true" 
                keyEntropyMode="ServerEntropy">
            </security>
            <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
            <httpsTransport authenticationScheme ="Negotiate" requireClientCertificate ="false" realm =""/>
        </binding>
    </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

Only problem is we're creating our binding programmatically not via the config. So if someone could point me in the right direction in regards to changing my BasicHttpBinding into a custombinding that conforms to the .config value provided I'll give them a big shiny gold star for the day.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Solved it!

Here's the winning code for those who are in a similar predicament.

```
Uri epUri = new Uri(_serviceUri);
CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();
SecurityBindingElement sbe = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
sbe.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11;        
sbe.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Strict;
sbe.IncludeTimestamp = false;
sbe.SetKeyDerivation(true);
sbe.KeyEntropyMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityKeyEntropyMode.ServerEntropy;
binding.Elements.Add(sbe);
binding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));
binding.Elements.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement());
EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress(epUri);
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. I had a similar issue where I had to create another class project that contained logic to perform an external service call.  I really didn't (couldn't) move the config from the app.config to the underlying web.config - and so the above solutions is perfect for this instance, to override the service definition.

Comment: Thank you - Had a C# dll to be consumed by Coldfusion so ...no app.config :( Your example helped me with adding the TextMessage encoding and https transport to the Custom Binding - Much appreciated!

Comment: how do I add basic auth to this custom binding?

Answer (score 8):

@D. Forrest already found the solution, but a simple way to see what objects are involved for a given WCF configuration is to call `.Endpoint.Binding.CreateBindingElements()` on the client proxy you are using.  You can the dump the object tree of each item in the list that is returned and see how the binding is configured.

Comment: Thanks a lot for mentioning this method! I'm using it to convert an existing `NetTcpBinding` to a custom binding at runtime in order to enable GZIP compression. This way I don't need to figure out how to do the conversion manually, nor do I need to hardcode the required binding elements.

Comment: Turns out it's even easier – you can simply pass any existing `Binding` to the `CustomBinding` constructor and don't need that method at all. Also documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-customize-a-system-provided-binding#to-modify-a-system-provided-binding). Might be obvious to people who are familiar with WCF but maybe this helps some other confused souls like me :)

Answer (score 2):

**You can use :**

```
        Uri epUri = new Uri("http://localhost/TestWCFService/Service.svc");
        CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding()
        {
            Name = "anyname",
            ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0, 0),
            SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0, 0),
        };
        var element1 = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement()
        {
            ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
            {
                MaxDepth = 2147483647,
                MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647,
                MaxArrayLength = 2147483647,
                MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647,
                MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647
            }
        };
        var element2 = new HttpsTransportBindingElement()
        {
            ManualAddressing = false,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
            AllowCookies = false,
            AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous,
            BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
            MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
            ProxyAuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous,
            TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
            UseDefaultWebProxy = true
        };
        var element3 = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

        binding.Elements.Add(element1);
        binding.Elements.Add(element2);
        binding.Elements.Add(element3);

        //binding.Elements.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement());

        EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress(epUri);
        var client = new ServiceClient(binding, endPoint);
```